# How can i prevent multiple events on change of Angular form Field

Tags: angular

I have a form which has several fields one of them is called bucketfilter where user can of which bucket he would like to retrieve.So to get all changes to the filter i subscribe to the buckerfilter on change like

```
  this.massEmailForm.get('bucketfilter').valueChanges.subscribe(val => {
            console.log('Value of Bucket Filter Change')
         });
```

this works fine and triggers the change but in my case causes the event to be fired several times. So if user selects 2 or 3 it will fire 2 or 3 times as i guess the change is gradually and not an all in one. So the question is there a way to delay this onchange event so it is only called ones not multiple times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correct you need [debounceTime](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/debounceTime). If the user change `massEmailForm` n-th times during time declared in the `debounceTime` operator you will have only the one (last) event in the stream.

```
this.massEmailForm.get('bucketfilter').valueChanges
  .pipe(debounceTime(/* ms */))
  .subscribe(val => {
    console.log('Value of Bucket Filter Change')
  });
```